# latinate or other words of foreign origin as opposed to Germanic words

Tags: vocabulary

In the following video (https://youtu.be/tNZXy6hfvhM?t=1062), the speaker feels the need to add after the adjective of Latin origin she first uses its equivalent based on purely German elements :

- Es gibt ja jetzt schon irreversible Schäden, also unumkehrbare Schäden…

Is she afraid *irreversibel* won't be as widely understood as *unumkehrbar*?  Is it a case of *irreversibel* being restricted to scientific discourse?  Given a choice is the *Verdeutschung* (if that's the right word) preferable?  Are there general trends that can be identified in this area?

Comment: It's not unusual (and never was) that speakers explain scientific terms with some more broadly understandable for native speakers in the audience.

Comment: *Irre* means "crazy"; maybe there was a need to disambiguate for some mor so than with other Latin baggage.

Comment: *Bleibende Schäden* would be less ... I don't know, just less.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The words *irreversibel* and *unumkehrbar* seem to be used with about the same frequency. Duden, under *Häufigkeit* ([irreversibel](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/irreversibel) [unumkehrbar](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/unumkehrbar)), lists both as belonging in the group of the 10<sup>4</sup> to 10<sup>5</sup> most frequent words. A quick search in the [Deutsches Referenzkorpus](http://www1.ids-mannheim.de/kl/projekte/korpora/releases.html) confirms this, with 8407 : 8721 hits.

Now even though the numbers may hide the fact that these words are used with different frequencies in different types of texts, they make me fairly confident in asserting that *irreversibel* is not *babble* as Janka suggests, but a pretty unremarkable word and definitely not limited to scientific discourse.

Per se, none of these words are preferable over the other. [Sprachpurismus](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutscher_Sprachpurismus) is a thing of the past, although contemporary [Sprachkritik](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprachkritik) may still criticise the unnecessary use of words of foreign origin when an acceptable native word is available, as is the case here.

Janka's post is a strong testament to the negative reaction you may garner if you go against that injunction. So one could add to your quite reasonable suggestion that the speaker in your video adds *unumkehrbar* in order to translate *irreversibel* for those that don't know the word the following: that she is aware of the injunction and is, in a manner, correcting herself in order to follow it.

To turn this back to the beginning: Despite the still-present injunction against the unnecessary use of loan words, *irreversibel* is used as frequently as *unumkehrbar*, which could be taken to mean that most people do not care either way.

## Addendum

This post is already long enough as it is, but I wanted to introduce two further examples (or classes of examples).

1. *ganzheitlich* and *holistisch* are one frequency level apart. Very likely, this means that *holistisch* is used in more specific contexts (it may be technical language) or only by the more educated (or those wishing to appear so).
2. *einen Anreiz schaffen* and *inzentivieren*. The latter is so rare as to not be listed in dictionaries. It might be a technical term in the narrowest sense, i.e. a term that is only known by specialists in a certain subject. It is felt to be a lazy and unnecessary loan from English, perpetrated by people who encounter *incentivise* in English texts and cannot be bothered to translate the term.

Of course, with time, *inzentivieren* may move up to the status of *holistisch* and on to that of *irreversibel*.

Comment: Those frequency dictionaries have the disadvantage they only cover written texts, most of which written by people with higher education. This makes them completely useless for this kind of problem.

Comment: @Janka Don't throw the baby out with the bathwater. The bias introduced by being  limited to written texts is not so big as to render all results derived from analysing those texts invalid.

Comment: @David _"Don't throw the baby out with the bathwater."_ Are you sure that this is a common English phrase? ;-)

Comment: @DavidVogt     Very insightful answer, thank you!

Comment: The common youtube audience has very little overlap with the smaller Die Zeit reader. Your argument is based on a faulty comparison.

Answer (score 5):

It's not *Verdeutschung*, *unumkehrbar* is the correct term.

*Irreversibel* is science babble or worse, regular babble. You cannot expect German speakers with less than college education will understand it. And even most people who know what it means won't use it outside of a scientific context either.

Non-professional speakers with a higher education often forget they are talking to people out of their bubble.

Advertising often uses Latin terms as *Sensitiv* or *Cerealien* to sound "professional". It sounds completely aloof in reality. Those people also live in a bubble.

Comment: Das mit der angeblichen _"Verdeutschunng"_ sehe ich ganz genauso. _Sensitiv_ und _Cerealien_ sind typischer Werbesprech der _"wissenschaftlich"_ daherkommen möchte. Alles Quatsch. Danke für diese Antwort!

Comment: Wenn z.B. ein Physiker von einem *irreversiblen Prozess* spricht, dann benutzt er absichtlich das Wort *irreversibel*, damit jeder weiß, dass es um Entropie geht. Sonst benutzt er selbstverständlich das Wort *unumkehrbar*. Dann kommen die Baumschüler und denken, dass die Physiker toll geschwollen reden können und die äffen das dann bei jeder Gelegenheit nach.

Comment: I would have given +1, but I do not understand or second the claim "it is the correct term", _irreversibel_ would also be totally correct. It is not a semantic, but a stylistic difference. So I do not understand how you come to imply that _irreversibel_ would not be correct.

Comment: The asker made the claim the Latin term was preferable and the other a *Verdeutschung*. It's not that way. There are *Verdeutschungen* of many Latin, French and English terms but this isn't one.

Comment: If you go back that far you can argue almost any common word but those with undoubtly German stems only is taken from Latin, as this was the language of the scholars until the 18th century.

Comment: @Janka. I don't think I made any claim in my question. Since "irreversibel" seems to predate "unumkehrbar", I assumed that "unumkehrbar" was purposely and consciously modelled on the neo-Latin irreversibilis (no mention of it is to be found in the OLD). It is the exact parallelism between the formation of the two words that made me use the term "Verdeutschung" that you seem to take exception to, but maybe I should be using another term.